# The upper bound and lower bound of $\left\| A \right\|_{F}^{2} + \left\| B \right\|_{F}^{2} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-norms

If $a$, $b$ are both real numbers, then the inequality $2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$ holds true; If $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are both column vectors, then the inequality $2\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{b} \leq ||\mathbf{a}||^2_2 + ||\mathbf{b}||^2_2$ is also true, where $T$ means transpose operation and $||\cdot||_{2}$ is the l2-modulus of the vector. What I want to know is that if $A$ is a $m\times r$ matrix, and $B$ is a $n\times r$ matrix, does there exist a constant $c$ that makes the following form of inequality true?
$$
c\times ||AB^T||_{F}^2 \leq ||A||_{F}^2 + ||B||_{F}^2,
$$
or in the opposite form, is there a constant $d$, such that the following form of inequality holds true?
$$
 ||A||_{F}^2 + ||B||_{F}^2 \leq d\times ||AB^T||_{F}^2.
$$
Here $||\cdot||_{F}$ means the frobenius norm.

Comment: We have $$\|AB^{\top}\|_F\leq\|A\|_F\|B\|_F\leq\frac{\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2}{2},$$ but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: The opposite form cannot hold true because if the columns of $A$ are orthogonal to the columns of $B$, then $AB^T$ is a zero matrix, making the right hand side zero when the left is not.

Comment: Yes, you are right.@WolfgangBangerth, I think I've given up on it. The answer of @Sangchul Lee is also right, and that's I want.